# How can I get the ID of a record when it isn't mentioned on a form in Access 2007 via VBA?

Tags: database, forms, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have a multiple items form which does not mention the ID of the record.  I have a button for each row which, when clicked, opens up a new form containing more details.

In the past, I've added a field for the ID but made it invisible, but this seems silly - the ID is a unique field of the original query, so I should be able to access purely with code somehow.

Does anybody know how to do this?  Let me know if you want more clarification.

**Update**

The fastest way for me to do this is to add a field in the form for the field in the query, call it the query field name, save it all and close it, then delete the field.  Though of course I'd rather just be able to do Me.ID without any of that prior nonsense.

Comment: Compile error: Method or data member not found.  So it's not recognising its existence at all.

Comment: In some cases, you may have to refer to Me!ID, rather than Me.ID because the field has not been added as a property of the form (discussion: http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1127364)

Comment: @Remou Ah that's it, thank you!  Go ahead and add that as an answer and I'll give you the check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some cases, you may have to refer to Me!ID, rather than Me.ID because the field has not been added as a property of the form (discussion: http://tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1127364 )

When you add the ID as as control and then delete it, it becomes a property of the form, which is why your work-around works.

Answer (score 1):

If a form's record source includes a field named "ID", you can access the field's value as a property of the form:

```
Debug.Print Me.ID
```

That works without a control bound to the field.

Comment: I'm able to access some of the not included fields using Me._____, but when I create a new one it doesn't work.  It seems that you need to use that field on the form, and even if you stop using that field, the Me._________ still works.  I'll keep playing around with this to reach a conclusion.

Comment: "*when I create a new one it doesn't work*"  Create a new what?  I don't understand what you're saying.  I just created a new form in Access 2007 whose record source is a query which includes a field named "id", and that field is not used as the control source for any of my form's controls.  Still I can retrieve the field's value for the current row with `Me.id`

Comment: Sorry, I'll clarify - when I created a new field on the original query and tried to use in my VBA code, I wasn't able to.

Comment: I just did it that way for a brand new form.  I first created it without "id" in the record source query, then revised the query to include "id", and `Me.id` works without a control bound to "id".  If it's still not working for you, save the modified form, close it and re-open it.

Comment: I tried saving and closing everything, then opening it all up again, but still doesn't work.  The most direct way I've found is to add a new field for the ID, call it 'ID', reference that in the VBA, save and close everything, and then I can delete the field and it works fine.  If I don't make the field I'm unable to get it to work... it's frustrating that it works fine on your end but not mine.  I even tried making a new form and unrelated query and it still doesn't work.

Comment: I can't explain why it's not working the same for you as it is for me.  I tested with both MDB and ACCDB format db files.  If you haven't installed SP3 for Office 2007, do it.  I would then try a new database file with a simple table, query and form.  And try a different machine if you have one with Access installed.

Comment: Seems like I don't have any service packs for Office - perhaps this is the issue.  I'm not sure if I'll be able to get it as our IT is quite strict.  My laptop with '10 is at home, I'll test that and if it works, how about you just make a comment in your answer of making sure to have SP3 then I'll give you the check.  Don't really want to leave this an unanswered question.

Answer (score 0):

you probably need to edit the recordsource / query.. and add that column as an available field.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't explicit enough, the ID was already part of the original query.